# .htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.2, http-status-code-404

I have a `.htaccess` file in `/var/www`, the contents of which is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

In `apache2.conf` `AccessFileName` is `.htaccess`, and `AllowOverride` does not exist. For some reason, visiting `example.com/anything` does not show `404.html`.

Comment: "and `AllowOverride` does not exist" - does not exist _anywhere_ in the server config? The default setting on Apache 2.2 is `AllowOverride All`, however, `AllowOverride None` is often defined in the main server config to disable `.htaccess` for the server.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure a suitable [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) setting in your configuration file to get [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) to work. The override you require is `fileinfo`  e.g.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    .
    .
    .
    AllowOverride fileinfo 
 </Directory>
```

Comment: I added:
`<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>` to apache2.conf (there was no directory thing already). And it made no difference.

Comment: @JJ56: Ok, that was an example because I don't know your configuration. You should put the AllowOverride directive within the Directory block that makes sense to your configuration. Don't forget to restart you Apache too.

Comment: Where is the directory block? There is none in ports.conf, apache2.conf, or httpd.conf. I added the one to apache2.conf, but 404 still dosen't work.

Comment: @JJ56: Which OS/distro are you using ?

Comment: ubuntu server edition 10.10

Comment: all i really know about my apache configuration is that i used "tasksel --section-server" and chose LAMP server.

Comment: @JJ56: Ubuntu splits the httpd configuration across several files. You should find the configuration you need to change in`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`.